# Getting CORS error in AngularJS when accessing data form REST URI

Tags: angularjs, json, server, cors

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://hfdvcbapp01.vm.itg.corp.us.shldcorp.com:8180/cnb/cnb/report/summary?Company=IT. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://127.0.0.1:64033' is therefore not allowed access.

I am getting this error when i am trying to load data from json which situated at the server.How can i  resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

Your api is not returning header

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://yourdomain.com
```

to allow specific domain

or

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

to allow all

PS. Also make sure that headers are actually there. Pay attention that CORS actually send 2 requests 1 will be **OPTIONS**, second will be actual request so if you return headers only on **GET** or **POST** it wont work. To check it in chrome presss f12, go to network and do you requests make sure that header is there
[Read more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)

Comment: I've tried this thing also.But still its not working

Comment: @Akshay there is no where! it depends what you have on backend

Comment: Thank you Volodymyr Bilyachat

Answer (score 0):

**Access-Control-Allow-Origin header should be set in the response,**

if it is not from the same origin of the URL it was sent from, the header should be set from the respone - meaning - the server responding to the request in youre case - http://hfdvcbapp01.vm.itg.corp.us.shldcorp.com:8180, 
if the server is under youre control just handle it, if its an outside service you should request this.

Comment: Thank you.I have tried this also but again showing same error.What should i do????????